# Kendo Window Scrolling background window

Tags: kendo-ui, window, scroll, event-bubbling

I have a kendo window popping up with info that the user can scroll through.  When the bottom/top of this window is reached via mouse scrolling, the background window then begins to scroll.  I want to be able to turn off this functionality without...

A) making the kendo window modal

B) setting overflow to hidden on the HTML->Body while the window is open

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For making the window modal use the property `modal : true`, for controlling the scroll when opening and restore when close use `open` and `close` event handlers.

```
var win = $("#win").kendoWindow({
    modal: true,
    open: function (e) {
        $("body").addClass("ob-no-scroll");
    },
    close: function(e) {
        $("body").removeClass("ob-no-scroll");
    }
}).data("kendoWindow");
```

In my case I've added a CSS definition called `ob-no-scroll` and then I add / remove it when open / close event are fired.

This CSS definition looks like:

```
.ob-no-scroll { 
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/HkwLS/

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
    $("#win1").kendoWindow({
        modal: true,
        open: function (e) {
            $("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden");
        },
        close: function (e) {
            setTimeout(function () { $("html, body").css("overflow", ""); }, 100);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

for 2017 version

```
$("#id").kendoWindow({
        modal: true,
        open: function (e) {
            $("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden");
        },
        e.preventDefault();
        ...
    });
```